# Wireless Access Point and Proxy Server Setup

Tags: wireless, dhcp

I was tasked to put up a network for a new department with about 7 users using wired and wireless connection.  Our Main network has DHCP and PROXY Server using Windows Server 2003.

Here's my simple diagram setup for the new department:

```
Main network     --> switch          --> wireless access point
(dhcp/proxy svr)     (wired systems)     (wireless systems)
```

Access Point Configuration:

- DHCP is Disabled
- local IP: acquired from DHCP
- WPA security disabled
- No other configuration applied to avoid complication.

Results:

- wired users can connect to the internet
- wireless users cannot connect to the internet

I compared the `ipconfig` of both wired and wireless clients and they have the same configuration.

Why are the wireless users unable to connect to internet?

Comment: "have the same configuration" - i want to verify you mean the IP network number, netmask and gateway are the same. Also, are the "can access" wired clients configured by DHCP as well?

Comment: yes, the acquired IP/gateway/DNS of the wired and wireless users are the same. thats why im wondering as to why the wireless users cannot access the internet.

Comment: ...how did this work out for you?

Comment: What can the wireless clients access?  Can they access each other?  The gateway?  The server(s)?  Another subnet on your LAN (if you have one)? Apart from that, what are the switch and AP vendor/model (so we know what information and/or options might be available for use)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've clarified (comments above) that IP net/mask/gw are the same for wired/wireless clients, then your AP is bridging (as opposed to routing or NAT'ing the wireless clients.)

1. Verify the wireless systems are getting DNS servers via DHCP. If "cannot access Internet" means "web sites do not load", this may be all that is wrong.
2. Verify your Internet edge router, (and/or firewall,) isn't blocking the traffic. You
   might have everything configured correctly from the network and IP
   point of view, and then not realize that the edge router has special
   rules to only permit certain of your internal LAN IP addresses out.
   (For example, your DHCP server could be configured to give specific
   IPs to certain DHCP clients (the boss's desktop), while servicing
   the rest of the clients (eg, printers) from a pool of numbers which aren't generally permitted out to the Internet.

Comment: OK Guys, Thanks for all your help, i will get back to you afterwards.. Ill try to check our network again tomorrow.  thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Are the WLAN interface and the Wired interface of the AP on the same Layer 2 network/VLAN?

If no, you need some kind of DHCP forwarders
If yes, there is something that seems to block your client's DHCP Discover broadcasts or the DHCP Offer from the server, most probably on the AP itself.

Comment: Our source is a single cable from the main network, which is connected to a SWITCH, then the WIRELESS ACCESS POINT is connected to the switch.

Comment: Be sure the AP is in bridging mode and does no routing whatsoever

You could use Wireshark (or any other network tracing tools) on your DHCP server and see if it receives the DHCP Discover from the wireless users.

If that's not the case and your switch has mirroring capability, you should trace the AP port, just in case some switch config are getting in the way.

If there is no mirroring capability or if it's an unmanaged switch, then that leaves the AP itself.  Depending on the brand/model, it might or might not be easy to find in the config/documentation

Comment: the switch has no other configuration, but i havent tried yet connecting the WIRELESS ACCESS POINT directly to the cable, this will remove the SWITCH.

Answer (score 0):

Three step process:

Reset AP to factory defaults
Connect to AP using Physical cable and change it's IP address to one of the existing being issued by main router
Disable DHCP of AP

After this, treat AP like normal wireless hub and configure (said and wep key etc).

Good luck